# How to add jars properly to a eclipse bundle

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, osgi

I got a little problem. I want to use hibernate in an eclipse rcp. (i'm new to osgi and eclipse rcp). So I added the jar into the plugin-project folder and the build path and the bundle build path, but when I try to use hibernate from my bundle, it crashes with a ClassNotFoundException.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pls look at eclipse buddy policy. This might help you if you are facing class not getting loaded because of `osgi` classloading.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate, and many other classic Java programs (ab)use dynamic class loading to to connect the different parts. They classes they use are read from a file and then loaded with Class.forName. This is fundamentally not-modular since these classes are by definition implementation classes, which should be hidden.

Since OSGi is a modularity framework it puts fences around a module (a bundle) and refuses to load anything that is not properly exported and imported. So if Hibernate does its Class.forName it will run right into this fence, as it should be to get the advantages of modularity.

Eclipse Buddy policy is like a huge hole in this fence, moving things back tot he bad old classpath: linear search. With a buddy policy, Eclipse will just start searching if there is a class somewhere that has that name. Since this ignores versions, you can no longer rely on proper version handling. The good news is that it works most of the time. The bad news is that you loose privacy and when it does not work you get weird errors.

With Hibernate, only solution is to not use the text file setup but use the API and give Hibernate the actual classes. In those cases Hibernate will use the class loader of those classes and that works. In OSGi, as long as you follow the Java language rules there are no problems.

To handle the kind of problems that class loading hacks address OSGi uses services.